# Edit many HTML-files with Regex, empty alt-tag once in 'img src' occurring twice

Tags: html, regex, tags, editor, notepad++

To begin and to be clear, I am using Regex to edit existing HTML code on many files and NOT to parse HTML.

Summary: The problem I am having to solve is that the content of the alt-tag in 'img src' gets removed. This for about 4500 HTML files.

Here is my the actual sample of the exisiting HTML Markup:

```
<!-- End Bottom Bar --><img src="image/sdim0490.jpg" alt="sdim0490.jpg" border="0" width="1" height="1" /><!-- Google Analytics Script -->
```

What I need to do is to remove the content of the alt-Tag so it's empty. There are about 4500 html-pages affected in various folders. I am using Notepad++ that allows editing of files contained in a folder using Regex.

The most difficult problem for me is that each HTML-page has at least 2 tags for 'img src', but I only need to edit one of them, actually the last occurence of it.

That one specific 'img src' tag is nested between the two comment-tags as shown in the example above, that is the case for ALL pages to be edited. But there is a but, sometimes there is an additional or even more empty line(s) above and/or below the comments. I know that doesn't make it simpler. But in every case both comments are there as outlined above and below. Of course the content of the alt-tag changes with every html-page and is never the same and unique for every page to be edited.

The result after applying the regex-edit should look like this:

```
 <!-- End Bottom Bar --><img src="image/sdim0490.jpg" alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1" /><!-- Google Analytics Script -->
```

It does not matter whether the extra empty lines above and/or below are removed or not. What matters only is that the alt-tag is empty.

Hope you may help me to create a regular expression that will NOT affect any other 'img src'-tag in the markup.

The reason for having an empty alt-tag is that a decorative or any other image that is not of significance to the content should be marked with en empty alt-tag. At least that what I was told about how search-bots value and differentiate images (among many other aspects).

You may wonder why I'm setting a width and height to '1'. Well I use this technique to pre-load the next image to be viewed that is of significance to the following page. This may increase the browsing experience for the user.

Looking forward to receiving some feedback.

Thank you for your attention, Hans.

**UPDATE to my question:**
After some more thinking I found that I've got a single value to search for. It's: border="0"
And that value is not needed at all. So an alternative would be to search for that and replace it as below including the preceding alt="xyz":

```
replace: alt="xyz" border="0" with: alt=""
```

That would serve my intention fully.

Comment: Is the alt attribute value the same on all these images you're removing? Or at least the same as the image filename? Also, isn't preloading usually done with JS these days?

Comment: Semantics. Write the 20 lines to do the edit with an HTML parser. You'll save time in the end. (You've already had to post this here.)

Comment: to 'You': Thanks for looking into this. The value for the alt-attribute changes in every file. The filename is different from that value. Preloading can be done in various ways, but it is not the issue here.

Comment: to 'TrueWill': Thanks too. Thanks for the suggestion using an HTML parser. How would you do that? (sorry not much an idea what you exactly mean).

Comment: @snahl Isn't your intention to use a program to perform the changes in all your 4500 HTML files ? Which language do you plan to use to write and run this program ? I can't imagine that you plan to do the changes using Notepad++ on each file. - I practice programmation with Python. Your need would be perfectly answered with a Python program. I will do it and I come back.

Comment: to 'eyquem': To me it doesn't matter which program to use to accomplish this. It's that I've got Notepad++ and it does search & replace over multiple files and folders with Regex. I've done it several times with rather simple tasks. I shy away using Python as I am not very familiar with that environment. It would require precise  instructions.

Comment: to 'eyquem': I've got Perl (from Active State) installation running. Will that do as well?

Comment: @snahl _" it does search & replace over multiple files and folders "_ Oh, fine ! I didn't know that, it's an interesting feature. So you can use the regex I put in the Python code in my answer in Notepad++ I think, you're not obliged to run a program in any other programming language.

Comment: @snahl You can use my regex in a Perl program, yes. By the way, installing Python is very fast: it takes 5 minutes when I do it (changing from one version to another or installing ancient version to answer certain questions)

Comment: @snahl I tried and succeeded to replace a chunk of string found with a regex in several files lying in a directory with the help of Notepad++. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes it’s good to sleep things over. This morning I had the idea that lead to the solution using Notepad++ (by the way this is a pretty decent editor).

Since the tag 'img src=' occurs at least twice I tried to a find a pattern that is unique to the tag 'img src='  in question. I did not occur to me earlier that ending height=”1” for the tag in question is unique enough. With this I did not need to take into account the lines above and below as I assumed initially. Also I removed the border=”0” as this data belongs into CSS and not into the mark-up.
Finally I got the search string I seeked for and  I entered is as follows (Search Mode: Regular Expression, checked)

Strings:
Search string:

```
alt="(.*).jpg"(.*)width="1" height="1" />
```

Replace string:

```
alt="" width="1" height="1" />
```

With the result of 3937 hits, Bingo. (so my assumption for the total of 4500 files was quite close).

Answer (score 1):

As you do not want to parse the HTML files, it is possible to use a regex to do what you wish.

In Python language, here's the code of the program that does it:

```
import re

text = '''<img src="image/sdim0490.jpg" alt="bling" border="0" width="1" height="1" />
<!-- End
Bottom Bar -->
##############################
<img src="image/sdim0491.jpg" alt="bling" border="0" width="1" height="1" />
##############################
<!-- Google

Analytics    Script
-->
<img src="image/sdim0492.jpg" alt="bling" border="0" width="1" height="1" />'''

regx = re.compile('(<!--\s+End\s+Bottom\s+Bar\s+-->'
                  '.*?'
                  '<img\s+src="image/.+?"\s+alt=")(.*?)("\s+.*? />'
                  '.*?'
                  '<!--\s+Google\s+Analytics\s+Script\s+-->)',
                  re.DOTALL)

print regx.sub('\\1\\3',text)
```

result

```
<img src="image/sdim0490.jpg" alt="bling" border="0" width="1" height="1" />
<!-- End
Bottom Bar -->
##############################
<img src="image/sdim0491.jpg" alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1" />
##############################
<!-- Google

Analytics

Script -->
<img src="image/sdim0492.jpg" alt="bling" border="0" width="1" height="1" />
```

`\s` is equivalent to `[ \t\n\r\f\v]` . I replaced the blanks in the pattern with `\s+` to take account of the fact that sometimes, in HTML files, the tagged-elements are broken by randomly placed newlines. That is a fact that is often used by opponents of treatment of SGML/HTML/XML files  with regexes to affirm that such files must always be treated with a parser, with which I don't agree. Note that I suppose in my code that such randomly placed newlines can occur between words, but not IN a word.

Comment: pretty neat. Thanks. Now I am sitting in front of the apparent solution and don't know how to apply it. I would not mind parsing the HTML, I mentioned it only because I was advised against it. It's a one time thing to edit-correct these files. So I don't care how it's done as long as I can do it. Would you mind assisting me further to get this done?

Comment: @snahl OK, if I can. I performed tests in Notepad++ with my regex. It doesn't work because of the dot, that seems to not have the same meaning in a regex passed to the Search window of Notepad++ than in Python. A dot in a regex's pattern used in Python matches with any character, apart ``\n`` . In Notepad++, it matches with no character, as far as I saw in my tests

Comment: @snahl So you are obliged to use my regex in a Perl program. Or to install Python.

Comment: great. Let me get my Perl back onto its feet. I will then get back to you by tomorrow as it's getting towards midnight here. Since you have provided the solution, maybe we should continue our conversation off this board. Decide for yourself. You can reach met at 'snah dot efpeol at niwulb dot hc'. No Regex needed for this just reverse each word. Thanks.

Comment: @snahl Please, write to me , because I sent you an email yesterday and it failed to be delivered. Write to eyguem@gmail.com . Note that it is eyguem, not eyquem

Answer (score 0):

Here's a regex... of course an html parser has distinct advantages.  It would be interesting to see which is faster.  My money is on the regex.  Maintainability likely goes to the html parser.

```
string input =@"<img src=""image/sdim0490.jpg"" alt=""bling"" border=""0"" width=""1"" height=""1"" />  <!-- End Bottom Bar --><img src=""image/sdim0490.jpg"" alt=""bling"" border=""0"" width=""1"" height=""1"" /><!-- Google Analytics Script -->  <img src=""image/sdim0490.jpg"" alt=""bling"" border=""0"" width=""1"" height=""1"" />";
string pattern = @"(?<=\<!-- End Bottom Bar --><img[^>]+alt="")([^""]*)(?="".*<!-- Google Analytics Script -->)";
string html = Regex.Replace (input, pattern, "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: to: 'agent-J': Thanks for the code.
Questions: 1) How should I run it? In Notepad++ I have a field for 'find what:' and 'replace with:' only. Don't know how to enter 3 strings.  2)Your input string has distinctive value for 'img src'. This value changes for each file processed, so this content should not being evaluated.  
Would be kind of you to please help me jump start this, thanks.

Comment: I don't know if notepad++ supports lookaheads, etc..  Try this in the replace dialog:  `(?<=\<!-- End Bottom Bar --><img[^>]+alt=")([^"]*)(?=".*<!-- Google Analytics Script -->)`

Comment: to 'agent-j': Hhm, tried it but no luck. What goes into the search field, this should be in Regex as well, right?

Comment: the expression I noted in the comment above is search field.  We want to replace that with empty.

Comment: to 'agent-j': nope that didn't do the job. Notepad++ can't find that string.

Comment: Here is another approach: I presume that the search and replace can be done on one line only, instead of multiple lines as stated earlier. This because the value of 'alt' is also contained in 'src' and it is unique.

Comment: uhps.....This because the value of 'alt' is also contained in 'src' and it is unique like follows: `<img src="image/sdim0490.jpg" alt="sdim0490.jpg" border="0"`. Hope this makes things easier. Sorry that I did not mention this earlier but I was not aware of it.

Comment: In other words the command could do like this: Read the content of 'alt' compare it to the trimmed content of 'img src' if there is no match continue and find the next 'alt' and compare. If there is a match, replace alt="xyz" border="0" with alt="". Too bad we can't read files from bottom up, as in this case it is the last instance of 'img src'.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sed command to clean the alts in img tags for all html files:

```
sed -i '' -e 's/(<img[^>]*?)alt="[^"]*"/$1alt=""/g' /somepath/*.html
```

Comment: to: 'Bohemian': Interesting, though it is important to replace only on  one and the last 'img src' tag per file, not all. What's an 'sed' command? Sorry, I have no clue.

Comment: As far as I understand **sed** well, it is a tool that analyses and treat each line of a file, line after line. But in the problem exposed by snahl, _"sometimes there is an additional or even more empty line(s) above and/or below the comments"_ So sed doesn't seem able to treat a line taking account of what the preceding lines or following lines are. Say me if I'm wrong, please.

Answer (score 0):

A more general solution for anyone who justs want to find any img tag with a non-blank alt attribute you could use this in notepad++ as well:

```
(<img [^>]*alt=")[^"]+("[^>]*>)
```

Replace the double quotes with quotes in the code if that's what you're using but you cannot mix the two in one expression because of the possible "Person's object" edge-case where an apostrophe is used between double quotes (or the rarer vice-versa).

Then in the replace field you'd use the captures you got from the find:

```
\1\2
```

What the regex search does is:

1.) Find an open img tag

2.) Check that it has an alt attribute before the img tag closes

3.) Make sure the alt tag isn't blank already

Then the replace simply ignores the content that was between the quotes and the output is a blank alt attribute. With a few modifications you could find the alt attributes that are empty and fill them, or re-fill the ones with content or all kinds of things.